# I keep getting this error "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_8_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (705, 66, 1)"

Tags: python, keras, tensor, valueerror, mlp

'MLP'

'define and fit model on a training dataset'

```
def fit_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    'define model'
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=2, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    'compile model'
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['acc'])
    'fit model'
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=100, batch_size=66, verbose=0)
    return model, history

# fit model on train dataset
model, history = fit_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy)
# evaluate model behavior
summarize_model(model, history, trainX, trainy, testX, testy)
# save model to file
model.save('model.h5')
```

Comment: Please post a properly formatted [mre] - see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass them as list, you cant have 4 different arguments

```
def fit_model(train, test):
```

and call fit like this

```
fit_model([trainX, trainy], [testX, testy], batch_size=16, epochs=100)
```